# Proving the linear magnification boundedness theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove the problem 3.1.16. b.) from the *Calculus and Analysis in Euclidean Spaces* by Shurman et al.: Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear mapping. As all linear maps are continuous and the absolute value function on $\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous, the composite function $|T|: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Given that $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\mid |x| = 1\}$ and the fact that as a continuous function, $|T|$ attains its maximum $c$ over $S$, show that $|T(x)| \leq c|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Here's where I'm stuck: At first glance the inequality seems like an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. However for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $|T(x)|$ = $\sqrt{\left<T(x), T(x)\right>}$, so there isn't much from where to take the inequality. Okay, so we can try to proceed by cases. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $|x| = 1$, then the inequality holds trivially. But then how to argue about $|x| \neq 1$? We know that as $T$ is a linear mapping, it follows that $T(x) = Ax$ for some matrix $A$. But I don't have the tools to continue the proof beyond this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $T$ is linear. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\frac{x}{|x|}\in S$ (because $\bigg|\frac{x}{|x|}\bigg|=\frac{|x|}{|x|}=1$), so
$$|T(x)|=|T(|x|\cdot\frac{x}{|x|})|=|T(\frac{x}{|x|})|\cdot|x|\leq c|x|$$
by the definition of $c$.